# Map from the stack of coherent sheaves on a curve to the Grothendieck group

Tags: algebraic-curves, algebraic-stacks, coherent-sheaves, picard-group

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective curve. We let $Coh(X)$ be the stack of coherent sheaves on $X$. Its Grothendieck group is $Pic(X)\times\mathbf{Z}$. Is the map
$$
Coh(X)\rightarrow Pic(X)\times \mathbf{Z}
$$
sending a coherent sheaf to its class in the Grothendieck group algebraic?

Comment: Yes, there is a 1-morphism of algebraic stacks as you describe.

Comment: Thanks ! Is it something obvious that can be generalized to any category having a moduli stack of objects ? I assume we also have to define a algebraic stack structure for the Grothendieck group. Do you have any reference where I can have a look to get a better understanding of this ?

Comment: I do not know about the general case, and I doubt that the K-group has a natural structure of algebraic stack (think about the associated graded that is the Chow group).  For curves, this is “classical”.  One construction using the determinant of a perfect complex is given in Definition 2.11 of my article with de Jong and He.